# wrong is_identity in sys.columns for inline functions

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a problem with `sys.columns` for inline functions.
Maybe an error of SQL Server or I'm missing something?

Let's start from beginning, I have a simple table and a simple function like these:

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[SimpleTable]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SimpleTable](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [descr] [varchar](50) NULL
    )
GO

DROP VIEW SimpleView
GO

CREATE VIEW SimpleView
AS
SELECT * FROM SimpleTable
GO

DROP FUNCTION SimpleFunction
GO

CREATE FUNCTION SimpleFunction(
    @dummy INT = NULL
)
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN
SELECT * FROM SimpleTable
GO
```

I can insert a row into SimpleTable using both a direct "table insert" or indirect "function insert" like this:

```
INSERT INTO SimpleTable (descr) VALUES ('DIRECT TABLE INSERT');
INSERT INTO SimpleView (descr) VALUES ('VIEW INSERT');
INSERT INTO SimpleFunction(DEFAULT) (descr) VALUES ('INLINE FUNCTION INSERT');

SELECT * FROM SimpleTable;
```

yes, it works..

```
id  descr
1   DIRECT TABLE INSERT
2   VIEW INSERT
3   INLINE FUNCTION INSERT
```

When I try to insert rows with explicit NULLs or explicit values in column `id` both SimpleTable and SimpleFunction insert, behave the same way:

```
INSERT INTO SimpleTable (id, descr) VALUES (3, 'DIRECT TABLE INSERT')
INSERT INTO SimpleView (id, descr) VALUES (5, 'VIEW INSERT')
INSERT INTO SimpleFunction(DEFAULT) (id, descr) VALUES (4, 'INLINE FUNCTION INSERT')

Server: Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'SimpleTable' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
Server: Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'SimpleTable' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
Server: Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'SimpleTable' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

and

```
INSERT INTO SimpleTable (id, descr) VALUES (null, 'DIRECT TABLE INSERT')
INSERT INTO SimpleView (id, descr) VALUES (NULL,'VIEW INSERT')
INSERT INTO SimpleFunction(DEFAULT) (id, descr) VALUES (null, 'INLINE FUNCTION INSERT')

Msg 339, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.
Msg 339, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.
Msg 339, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.
```

So there is no difference and the column id is recognized and treated as identity in both ways.

But now, let's take a look into `sys.columns`:

```
SELECT o.name o_name, o.type, o.type_desc, c.name c_name, c.is_identity
FROM sys.objects o
JOIN sys.columns c on o.object_id = c.object_id
where o.name in ( 'SimpleTable', 'SimpleFunction')
and c.name = 'id' 

o_name          type    type_desc                           c_name  is_identity
SimpleTable     U       USER_TABLE                          id      1
SimpleView      V       VIEW                                id      1
SimpleFunction  IF      SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION    id      0
```

and also `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` (thanks to @Jeroen Mostert):

```
Type    name    source_table    source_column   is_identity_column  is_updateable   is_nullable is_part_of_unique_key
U       id      SimpleTable     id              1                   0               0           1
V       id      SimpleTable     id              1                   0               0           1
IF      id      SimpleTable     id              0                   1               0           1
```

**As you can see, the identity column of SimpleTable is not marked as identity in function structure.**

My question is WHY?

I'm using a `DbCommandBuilder` in .NET and it produces wrong queries because of that.

I have tried to manually change it but it is no more possible since SQL server 2008.

Comment: [`INSERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms174335#TargetObjects) isn't documented to work at all with table-valued functions -- only with tables, table variables, views, and `OPENQUERY`. So congratulations for discovering this works, to some degree. Given that it's there, the behavior ought to be consistent with views (which do propagate the info), but it's not, not even `WITH SCHEMABINDING`. I recommend opening a bug report on Microsoft Connect if this is intended behavior or something that should be fixed (but I don't actually expect them to fix it, to be honest).

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you very much for your valuable help. I have tested also with views and it works fine (see updated answer). I have opened a ticket for this strange behaviour [wrong metadata returned for table valued functions and identity columns](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3107621)