# why is the nullability different for same column in same query in 2 identical databses

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016, nullable

I have 2 identical databases. 1 test db by me, and 1 production db by the customer

I have a (simplified) query that looks like this

```
ALTER VIEW nulltest as 
SELECT isnull(NextDate,getdate()) as TillDate  FROM (
SELECT   LEAD(FromDate) OVER (partition by personid ORDER BY fromdate) AS NextDate
FROM   Taxes)t
```

In reality the TillDate column will never be null, since it has an `ISNULL` function. But when i check the nullability of the query, i get 2 distinct answers. I check with this query

```
SELECT sys.columns.is_nullable FROM sys.columns  INNER JOIN sys.objects ON sys.columns.object_id = sys.objects.object_id and sys.objects.name='nulltest'
```

On my db, I get a 1, and on the prod server I get a 0.

What gives?

**UPDATE**

FromDate in both databases is `datetime2, not null`

`@@Version`

DB 1: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB4019089) - 13.0.4206.0 (X64) 
    Jul  6 2017 07:55:03 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials 6.3  (Build 9600: )

DB 2: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64)   Feb 20 2014 20:04:26   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: What's the nullability of `Taxes.FromDate` in both databases?

Comment: Also, what does `SELECT @@VERSION` give on both systems, and what's the DB compat level? This could be a difference in optimizers.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is related to updatable views.

`is_nullable = 0` means that you can't set that column to `NULL` and in this case `is_nullabe` is related to `TillDate` column of `nulltest` view,
and not its source `FromDate` column in `Taxes` (table/view/function I don't know what).

if you try to do something like:

```
UPDATE nulltest SET TillDate = NULL WHERE TillDate = GETDATE()
```

If `TillDate` `is_nullable = 0` it should give you an error.

Now, the reason why in two different servers it gives you different nullability can be related to sql-server version and support for updatable views.

I had a similiar (unresolved) problem with `is_identity_column` with table valued functions. ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149576/wrong-is-identity-in-sys-columns-for-inline-functions))

Maybe in your db, where you get `is_nullable = 1`, this kind of views, using window functions (`LEAD`) will result in something similar to my table valued function and its problems..